# WooCommerce product category and product tag base product permalink not working

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product

my website link
https://momsbasement.net/product-category/accessories/
please check image
 I have added the product permalink(Settings ->Permalinks) to image

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Permalinks works only woocommerce defalut pages, you have made custom templates for shop and category pages. that's why its not working correctly.
Thanks